# Setting to a table from a Tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like a method of writing writing to a table whenever an Entry box is updated. The entry boxes are generated from a for loop on the tables keys.

Here's an example of what I have:

```py
profiles = {
"Test": 0.5
"AnotherTest": 0.75
}

for i,v in profiles:
  tempvar = tk.DoubleVar()
  entry = ttk.Entry(root, width = 6, textvariable = tempvar)
```

I have tried using `trace_add` however the callback does not give a name:

```py
>>> trace_callback(var, index, mode):
>>>   print(f"Variable: {var} Index: {index} Mode: {mode}")
```

```
Outputs: "Variable: PY_VAR1 Index:  Mode: write" whenever you type new text into the Entry box
```

I have also tried `validatecommand` with the same situation.

Comment: *"the callback does not give a name"* What name do you want? It is not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variables name using the third parameter of `Tk.Variable.<vartype>`:

```py
var = tk.DoubleVar(root, 0.0, "CustomName")
```

Use `tk.globalgetvar(var_name)` to retrieve the variables value from inside `trace_add()`

```py
>>> trace_callback(var, index, mode):
>>>   print(f"Variable: {var} Index: {index} Mode: {mode} Value: {root.globalgetvar(var)}")
```

```
Outputs: "Variable: CustomName Index:  Mode: write Value: 0.0"
```

Comment: Unless the OP needs a human-readable name, it's not necessary to provide a custom name. `globalgetvar` will work without a custom name.